# Google mini and google image

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I need to search a text catched from google assistant on google images. Through the IFTTT service I can read the TEXT and write it on a spreadsheet, but i have no idea how to search the stored text on the internet. 
Any idea? 
My wish is to say "ok google show a horse" and it to see a horse's image on my TV through chromecast

Comment: This is far too vague, please read up on the rules of Stackoverflow and post more details such as which programming language and the code that you have thus far.

Comment: Noble goal, but agree with above comment.